# Service for posting data to server in Android even if app is closed (offline to online)

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am working on an android app, which will take input from the user (sort of form, simulated chat) and store it in the local database.
I have created BroadcastReceiver to get the network changed status, if connected I start posting the data to the server.

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiverService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Connectivity.isConnected(context)) {
            Logger.d("Connected to internet");
            // Post data to the server.
        } else {
            Logger.d("Not connected to internet");
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the right approach. Would be a great help if you specify the details of the posting the data to the server, like should I use AsyncTask or go with just the plain Retrofit thing, I want to keep the memory consumption as low as possible while the receiver and posting works in the background. Alos, if, possible would like to know the working of WhatsApp for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can write services and AlarmManager to do so. Simply register your application in services and call alarmMangaer.setRepeat() method to start your code of serverside or any other operation you want to do in onStart() method of services.

```
public class MyService extends Service{
  Calendar cur_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  @Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
            0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            60 * 1000*3, pintent);
}
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
          // your code for background process
  }
}
```

Add this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<service
        android:name="com.yourpackage.MyService"
        android:enabled="true" />
  <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedIntentReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Edit: BootCompletedIntentReceiver.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);
        }
    }
}
```